# What should I use instead of putchar() for 16-bit data?

Tags: c, gcc

I am fairly new to C, and have written a simple program which generates a sine wave with a specified frequency and sample rate, and sends that to stdout as an unsigned 8-bit byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t sinco(int iCarrier, int iSampleRate, unsigned long ulIndex){return (sin(iCarrier * (2 * M_PI) * ulIndex / iSampleRate) * 127) + 128;}

void main(){    
    unsigned long t;
    const int iCarrier = 500;
    const int iSampleRate = 8000;

    for(t=0;;t++){
        putchar(sinco(iCarrier, iSampleRate, t));
    }
}
```

I realize that putchar() was not the most appropriate function, but it worked for what I needed at the time. Now I am currently trying to modify the program to output an unsigned 16-bit number, but I'm not sure what to replace putchar() with.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t sinco(int iCarrier, int iSampleRate, unsigned long ulIndex){return (sin(iCarrier * (2 * M_PI) * ulIndex / iSampleRate) * 65535) + 65536;}

void main(){    
    unsigned long t;
    const int iCarrier = 500;
    const int iSampleRate = 8000;

    for(t=0;;t++){
        printf(%hu, sinco(iCarrier, iSampleRate, t));
    }
}
```

However once the value gets larger than 65,536, the program starts sending 32 bits to stdout. Is there a better alternative to putchar I can use which will correctly wrap around?

Comment: If `wchar_t` is 16 bits on your platform, how about `putwchar` in wchar.h?

Comment: Split your sample into two bytes. This lets you choose endianness. With the same technique you can also fill a ~50ms `char[4096]` buffer with 2048 sample and `write(1,buffer,4096);` them all in one go.

Comment: Is the intent to print out the sample as a set of ASCII characters representing the binary value, or to use stdout for binary output? If the latter, I would highly recommend just writing a file so you don't break anyone's terminal.

Comment: @Linuxios This application needs to interface with different destinations in different contexts, and I've found that piping the output is the quickest way to do so. I had considered writing a file, but that doesn't work for some of my use cases.

Comment: @Skoddie: OK. Might just want to add some kind of check of whether stdout is a terminal and abort.

Comment: @Linuxios Good call, I will do that as a typo actually took my system down at one point. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, comes from personal experience `cat`ing the wrong files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to output a value that is encoded in two bytes. So output these two bytes successively. Which two bytes? It depends on how the 16-bit value is supposed to be encoded in two 8-bit values, i.e. on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system that will read those two bytes.

Little-endian:

```
uint16_t w = sinco(…);
putchar(w & 0xff);
putchar((w >> 8) & 0xff);
```

Big-endian:

```
uint16_t w = sinco(…);
putchar((w >> 8) & 0xff);
putchar(w & 0xff);
```

If the system that reads the value has the same endianness as your CPU, then you can use a different strategy: write the value by dumping its memory contents. You can read any value in memory as an array of bytes, and you can use `fwrite` to write an array of bytes.

```
uint16_t w = sinco(…);
fwrite(&w, 1, 2, stdout);
```

Comment: Awesome. I had been considering doing exactly this, but wasn't sure that it was actually a good way to do it. Much appreciated!